# Do hindu Vedas refer Or and respect to religions?

Tags: vedas, philosophy, other-religions, brahma-sutras

Can someone please quote verses Or Vedas where Hindu religion acknowledges existence of other religion and guides to respect in their form?

Comment: I believe hindu dharma respect other religion but not sure if this is referred in some Vedas , I would be proud to know if we have such evidence.

Comment: ekam sat vipra bahudha vadanti (Rig Veda 1.164.46) 'Truth is One, men call it by various names' Also, Vyasa said 'We find perfect men even beyond the pale of our caste and creed.'

Comment: Vedas predate other religions and therefore don't need to acknowledge them. For information, everyone is a Hindu

Comment: Hinduism itself is not a religion, thus it does not speak about other religions. Hinduism is like a broad term for a collection of different religions. These religions are themselves sometimes conflicting. Some place more emphasis on one particular book, other place more emphasis on self knowledge, etc. Thus it would be difficult to define what 'Hinduism' says about people from other religions. Great saints like Ramakrishna Paramhansa, Paramhansa Yogananda, Shri Sai Baba, Swami Sivananda have said that all religions are equally valid and all lead to Happiness or Bliss. All the best Sir :) !!

Comment: there's nothing like other religion in any books of hinduism, because it only talks about the sanatanam or being human, secondly, religion is a mordern concept and nothing to do with ancient vedic science.